# Altura do meu site

Tags: html, jquery, css

Boa noite, fiz um site responsivo e fui testando no mozilla para ver como ficava nos dispositivos móveis e pareceu-me tudo bem, mas quando o coloquei no ar não ficou como eu esperava.

Assim foi como testei e como queria:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Assim era como queria quando se carregasse nos contactos:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E assim foi como ficou no telemóvel:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que posso fazer para que o meu site não tenha a dimensão do visor, mas sim a dimensão disponível já contando com as barras de definições dos navegadores, neste caso o safari do iphone?

Deixo o o meu código para que possam ver.
html:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    

 $('footer').on('click', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('sobe');
 });



 // Definir a altura do section entre a imagem e o footer
 var altura = $('#foto').height();
 $('section').css('height', '100vh').css('height', '-='+ altura).css('height', '-=44px');

 // Definir a altura da imagem dentro da section
 var altura_section = $('section').height();
   $('section img').css('height', altura_section);

});



$(window).resize(function(){
 var altura = $('#foto').height();

   $('section').css('height', '100vh').css('height', '-='+ altura).css('height', '-=44px');

   var altura_section = $('section').height();
   $('section img').css('height', altura_section);
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli');


* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
 overflow: hidden;
}

h3 {
 color: #025aa4;
 text-align: center;

}

#container {
 height: 100vh;
 width: 100%vw;
 margin: auto;
}

header {
 margin-bottom: -2px;
  width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 background: url('../_img/untitled-2.jpg') no-repeat ;
 background-size: 100vw;
 background-attachment: fixed;
}


section {
 width: 100vw;
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
}

section img {
  position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

section p {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  visibility: hidden;

 letter-spacing: 2px;
 word-spacing: 10px;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 350%;
 font-weight: bolder;
 
 text-shadow: 5px 5px 4px rgba(0,0,0, .6);
}


footer {
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 0px;
 width: 100vw;
 height: 40px;
  
 transition: height 1s ease;
}

.sobe {
    height: 100vh;
}

footer i {
 color: #025aa4;
}


footer .cabecalho-footer {
 position: relative;
 background-image: none;
 background-color: #025aa4;
 height: 40px;
 width: 100%;
 cursor: pointer;
}

footer .cabecalho-footer i {
 opacity: 0;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 30px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 right: 10px;
 transform: translate(-0%, -50%);
}


footer .cabecalho-footer h1 {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 18px;
 color: #fff;
 font-family: 'Advent Pro', sans-serif;
 letter-spacing: 3px;
}

footer .contacto-flow {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100vh;
 overflow: scroll;
 background-color: #fff;
}

footer .contactos {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 background: #fff;
  text-align: center;
 line-height: 25px;
 
}

footer .horario  {
 margin-bottom: 100px;
}



@media all and (orientation:landscape) {
 
 #container {
  position: relative;
 }
 
 section {
   position: absolute;
  top: 68%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -68%);
  padding: 80px;
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0, .5);
 }
 
 section img {
  visibility: hidden;
 }
 
 section p{
  visibility: initial;

 }
 
 footer .contactos {
  font-size: 20px;
 }
 
 
 .contactos p {
  line-height: 45px;
 }
}


@media screen and (min-width: 1025px) {
    footer .contacto-flow .contactos{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: auto;
    width: 75%;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px 5px  rgba(0,0,0, .2);
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-pt">
<head>

 <title>Estores JF</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_css/estilo.css">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <link rel="icon" href="_img/Estores_JF.png">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">

 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="_js/jquery.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
 <div id="container">
  
  <header>
   <img id="foto" src="_img/untitled-2.jpg" style="visibility: hidden; width: 100vw;" />
  </header>



  <section>
   <img src="_img/Brevemente.gif"/>
   <p>BREVEMENTE DISPONÍVEL!</p>
  </section>


 
  <footer>

   <header class="cabecalho-footer">
     <h1>CONTACTOS</h1>
     <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>

   </header>

   <div class="contacto-flow">
    <div class="contactos">

     <div class="morada">
      <br>
      <h3>Morada:</h3>
      <p><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp
      Rua Fonte da Carreira, nº 350 <br>
      Pav. A2, Parque Empresarial Fonte da Carreira <br>
      Adroana <br>
      2645-467 Manique</p> <br>

      <p><i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp
      N38°44'24" - W9°22'40"</p><br> 

     </div>

     <div class="contacto">
      <h3>Contacto:</h3>
      <p><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp
      Tel. 21 421 50 78</p>
      <p><i class="fa fa-fax" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp
      Fax. 21 421 13 21</p>
      <p><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp
      geral@estoresjf.com</p><br>
     </div>

     <div class="horario">
      <h3>Horário:</h3>
      <p><i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp
      2ª a 6ª das 9 - 12.30 / 14 - 17.30</p>
     </div>
     
    </div>
   </div>
   

  </footer>

 </div>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Você pode colocar um "padding-top" só para determinadas resoluções de tela usando @media por exemplo. Ou usar a meta tag "viewport" para ver se melhora... De qualquer forma coloque o seu código HTML e CSS que fica mais fácil para te dar uma resposta precisa.

Comment: @hugocsl eu usei media e usei a meta tag viewport e ficou desse jeito...
Já deixei o meu código, obrigado

Comment: Não entendo muito de JS, mas parece que ali vc está querendo colocar um espaço de 100vh - 44px correto? A ideia é válida, mas acho que ali que pode ter algo errado, apesar de eu não ter conseguido simular o erro por aqui.

Comment: Sim, para achar a altura certa do meu section, fiz a altura total da tela, menos 44px do footer e menos a altura da imagem que tenho @hugocsl... Testei agora no google chorme no telemóvel e deu como eu queria, acha que pode ser só do safari?

Comment: Acessei no Safari aqui no iPhone e me pareceu tudo ok, exceto a imagem do bonequinho segurando a placa que ficou cortado.

Comment: @dvd quando clicou nos contactos e ele subiu, a mesma barra azul de contactos continuou visível?

Comment: Sim, normal....